# Loop in function doesn't have access to global variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why this code doesn't work? I have a global variable which I need to assign value to it by getting data from json:

```
regional = ''

def getData(manager):
    with open("temp/"+manager+".json", 'r') as j:
        json_object = json.loads(j.read())
        for result in json_object['results']:
            username = (result['username'])
            if level == 1:
                regional = username
                print(username)
```

the print at the end works and shows the username but it doesn't assign it to regional which is the global variable. It's empty. In the VSCODE, it's showing as not accessible.

Comment: you can use `global regional` to get the global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare the variable as `global` to be able to modify it:

```
regional = ''

def getData(manager):
    global regional  # <- HERE
    with open("temp/"+manager+".json", 'r') as j:
        json_object = json.loads(j.read())
        for result in json_object['results']:
            username = (result['username'])
            if level == 1:
                regional = username
                print(username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use global keyword.
I recommand you to reference this page : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-keyword-in-python/